# Need help changing jquery to javascript for an on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change some jQuery code to plain JS for an on call function. I keep getting the following error - Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'.

Old

```
$(document).on('change', '.js-variant-radio', onVariantRadioChange);
```

New

```
document.querySelector('.js-variant-radio').addEventListener("change", onVariantRadioChange);
```

Complete code block here

```
(function(){
  //START QUANTITY INPUT VALIDATION FUNCTION
  let
    onVariantRadioChange = function(event) {
      let
        $radio = document.querySelector(this),
        $form = $radio.closest('form'),
        max = $radio.attr('data-inventory-quantity'),
        $quantity = $form.querySelector('.js-quantity-field'),
        $addToCartButton = $form.querySelector('.add-to-cart-button');

      if($addToCartButton.prop('disabled') === true) {
        $addToCartButton.prop('disabled', false);
      }

      $quantity.attr('max', max);

      if (parseInt($quantity.value) > max) {
        $quantity.val(max).change();
      }
    };

    //END QUANTITY INPUT VALIDATION FUNCTION
})();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're still adding the event listener with jQuery. Try changing it to:

```js
const jsVariantRadio = document.getElementsByClassName('.js-variant-radio')[0];

jsVariantRadio.addEventListener('change', onVariantRadioChange);
```

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as the answer. It is invalid in multiple ways. `getElementsByClassName` takes a regular string as an argument, not a selector - and you cannot add an event listener to a group of objects like this. They must be added one at a time (like from a loop). Lastly, OP wanted to convert their code into vanilla, whereas this addresses only the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code in vanillaJS. The only thing I didn't do is mimic the `change()` trigger that was appended

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let
    onVariantRadioChange = function(event) {
      let
        $radio = event.target,
        $form = $radio.closest('form'),
        max = $radio.dataset['inventory-quantity'],
        $quantity = $form.querySelector('.js-quantity-field'),
        $addToCartButton = $form.querySelector('.add-to-cart-button');

      if ($addToCartButton.getAttribute('disabled')) {
        $addToCartButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }

      $quantity.setAttribute('max', max);

      if (parseInt($quantity.value) > max) {
        $quantity.value = max;
      }
    };

  document.querySelectorAll('.js-variant-radio').foreach(el => el.addEventListener("change", onVariantRadioChange));
})
```